# What is a good focus point for street photography when using zone focusing?

Tags: manual-focus, street-photography, focus-point-selection, focusing-screen

For example, I am using Fuji X100T (35mm), and according to this video [1], Doug McKinlay suggested that turn to f8, and to focus at 10 feet distance, and so from 5 feet to infinity will be in focus, is it correct or commonly used for street photography?

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doteTgK2VYQ

Answer (score 3):

It is true that for a camera with a 23mm lens and crop factor 1.52 (inferring from your 35mm) that at f/8 the hyperfocal distance is a little over 10 feet (closer to 11 actually).

"Is it correct" is not the question you should be asking though.

What do you want from your photos?

Do you actually want to get the whole scene in focus from 5 feet beyond? Will you be shooting in good lighting conditions where you can get away with f/8? Do you want to be discreet and not risk people know you are taking their photo, shooting from the hip where you would rely on fixing your focus in this way. If so then that would be a reasonable decision.

However if you want to isolate your subject from their surroundings, or if you are shooting in poor lighting conditions and f/8 is forcing you into iso values that you are uncomfortable with then this approach isn't going to work.

Each scenario will require a different approach. It is up to you as a photographer to learn when each approach will give the results you want.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want to shoot from hip 5 feet beyond and now look like set my initial focus to 11 feet would be a good choice. I want to know beside this *trick*, are there any commonly used settings (e.g. other frequently used focal distances)? or do people focus and recompose on street if they are not using zone focusing? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same with my camera because it's a pain to focus manually (Olympus XA).

I suggest that rather than just taking someone's word for it, that you play around with a DOF/hyperfocal calculator and see what is ideal based on your camera/lens combination or combinations.

I use this one: [DOF Master](http://www.dofmaster.com/dofjs.html)